# What's the best way to ask for general advice on DB administration topic?

Tags: discussion

I asked a question on StackOverflow that was closed as "not constructive":
[Is Amazon RDS Backup sufficient or should you do your own as well?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12873416/is-amazon-rds-backup-sufficient-or-should-you-do-your-own-as-well)

I understand that my question doesn't lend itself to a specific, technical answer, which I assume is why it was closed. But it's a legitimate question about database administration policies and I'm looking for answers/advice/guidance from those more experienced than I.

How should I have asked this? Is there another StackExchange site that would have been a better fit?

Comment: Perhaps dba.stackexchange.com? Check out their [faq](http://dba.stackexchange.com/faq) to make sure.

Answer (score 4):

Your best bet might be to ask first in the DBA chat room:

> [The Heap](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/179/the-heap)

The people there might be able to either help you straight away or help you get your question shape for posting on the [DBA](https://dba.stackexchange.com/) site.